# Getting embed code for specific vimeo video, vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo

Ok, working on a vimeo based video blog theme for wordpress and rather than lazily ask people to paste the embed code into each video update (via a custom field), I'd rather the user supplied just the video id... basically I can't guarantee that each video is going to be the same height / width so I'm trying to get the embed code directly from vimeo (rather than getting the user to supply) rather than hardcoding a height / width for the iframe (as the theme is going to be responsive and I'm using a small jquery script to resize the videos on the fly)

So far, having tried to butcher Vimeo's own API example, I've got this:

```
function curl_get($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
} 

// Create the URL
$oembed_vid_id = get_field('video_embed_code');
$oembed_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $oembed_vid_id . '.xml';

// Load in the oEmbed XML
$oembed = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($oembed_url));
$embed_code = html_entity_decode($oembed->html);

<?php echo $embed_code ?>
```

But I get nothing back, have I overlooked something quite basic?

I can confirm that the $oembed_url URL does exist, try any vimeo id and you'll see the relevant xml for it, i.e. here's a video I've plucked from vimeo:

http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/48198301.xml

Would be fantastic if I could get to grips with this as I'll be able to pull down thumbnails etc. and make use of all that other lovely info tucked away in the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vimeo's Sample Code](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/blob/master/oembed/php-example.php), it seems that you are not using the right API.

`http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/` will return the video info fields, but doesn't have a `html` field. To get the embed code, use this URL:

```
$oembed_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.xml?url=' . urlencode("http://vimeo.com/$oembed_vid_id");
```

Comment: for some reason, that original API was the one I was having trouble with, with some googling I replaced it with the v2 link - but all seems to work now, thank you! might have been the urlencode part as I originally had it as $oembed_url = 'http://vimeo.com/etc..?url=http://vimeo.com/' . $oembed_vid_id;

Works perfect though, thank you :)